# How can I resume playing audio from web source after pausing it using HTML5 and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some web URLs in `tracks` array which I'm playing through HTML5 audio API in JavaScript. It pauses when I click on pause. But once paused, when I click on play, the audio starts playing from the beginning.

The HTML spec mentions the `audio.currentTime` property, so I've tried to track this in a separate variable called `currentTime` and set it before resuming again, but this does not seem to work as the audio *still* starts from beginning.

I've spent quite some time on experimenting and Googling, but I can't see what's going wrong here. There's no reason for the audio to not play from where I pause from looking at the logic of this code.

Has anyone else experienced this and know of a workaround?

Here's my js file:

```
$(function() {
    let trackTitle = $('#title');
    let prevBtn = $('#btn-prev');
    let playPauseBtn = $('#btn-play-pause');
    let nextBtn = $('#btn-next');
    let seekBarFill = $('.seek-bar .fill');

    let tracks = [
        'http://traffic.libsyn.com/minutephysics/Why_You_Should_Care_About_Nukes.mp4?dest-id=95145',
        'http://traffic.libsyn.com/minutephysics/.mp4?dest-id=95145',
        'http://traffic.libsyn.com/minutephysics/Transporters_and_Quantum_Teleportation.mp4?dest-id=95145',
        'http://traffic.libsyn.com/minutephysics/The_Limb_of_the_Sun.mp4?dest-id=95145',
        'http://traffic.libsyn.com/minutephysics/_1.mp4?dest-id=95145',
        'http://traffic.libsyn.com/minutephysics/Concrete_Does_Not_Dry_Out.mp4?dest-id=95145'
    ];
    let audio = new Audio();
    let currentTrack = 0;
    let currentTime = 0;

    function playTrack() {
        audio.src = tracks[currentTrack];
        trackTitle.html('<a href=' + tracks[currentTrack] + '>' + tracks[currentTrack] + '</a>');
        audio.currentTime = currentTime;
        audio.play().then(function() {
            $('#btn-play-pause img').attr('src', 'static/pause.png');
        });
    }

    function playOrPauseTrack() {

        if(audio.paused) {
            console.log('play clicked');
            audio.currentTime = currentTime; // attempted workaround, still not working
            playTrack();
            console.log('play/current time=' + audio.currentTime);
        } else {
            console.log('pause clicked');
            audio.pause();
            currentTime = audio.currentTime;
            console.log('pause/current time=' + currentTime);
            $('#btn-play-pause img').attr('src', 'static/play.png');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I should add that I'm attempting this on Safari 13.0.5. The same behaviour is also showing on Chrome 80.0.3987.149. My machine is running Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the audio element's `src` property, you reset everything.

Simply don't set it, and don't reset the `currentTime`.  All you have to do is call `.play()` to resume playing.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution and I was about to rip my hair out. Thanks! Will accept as answer after the ~10 mins cool-down period passes.

Comment: @samisnotinsane It's always the simplest things that are the most frustrating.  :-)